# AgileDotNet obfuscated code calls the wrong function

Tags: c#, obfuscation

After running AgileDotNet on a c# project, I have been preseneted with the most unusal error:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'qVQ=.qLQ=' does not contain a definition for 'MyFunctionActualName'
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
   at ohM=.oQM=.<OnCallback>d__21.MoveNext()     Program.cs::OnCallback() #449
```

C# is trying to call a function by it's actual name, that is: `MyFunctionActualName`. Since the code is obfuscated, of course function with name `MyFunctionActualName` does not exist anymore. Why does AgileDotNet try to call it? How does one debug such problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this exception is due to code using the `dynamic` type and then calling methods on such an instance.

Let me show you an example:

```
void Main()
{
    dynamic t = new Test();
    t.ActuallyNotPresentMethod();
}

public class Test
{
    public void Execute() => "test".Dump();
}
```

This throws:

> RuntimeBinderException: 'UserQuery.Test' does not contain a definition for 'ActuallyNotPresentMethod'

Let's take a look at the IL it produces, the `UserQuery` part comes from [LINQPad](https://linqpad.net), which I used to run the above example and get the IL below from:

```
IL_0000:  newobj      UserQuery+Test..ctor
IL_0005:  stloc.0     
IL_0006:  ldsfld      UserQuery+<>o__4.<>p__0
IL_000B:  brtrue.s    IL_0041
IL_000D:  ldc.i4      00 01 00 00 
IL_0012:  ldstr       "ActuallyNotPresentMethod"
IL_0017:  ldnull      
IL_0018:  ldtoken     UserQuery
IL_001D:  call        System.Type.GetTypeFromHandle
IL_0022:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0023:  newarr      Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo
IL_0028:  dup         
IL_0029:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_002A:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_002B:  ldnull      
IL_002C:  call        Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create
IL_0031:  stelem.ref  
IL_0032:  call        Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.InvokeMember
IL_0037:  call        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite<System.Action<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,System.Object>>.Create
IL_003C:  stsfld      UserQuery+<>o__4.<>p__0
IL_0041:  ldsfld      UserQuery+<>o__4.<>p__0
IL_0046:  ldfld       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite<System.Action<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,System.Object>>.Target
IL_004B:  ldsfld      UserQuery+<>o__4.<>p__0
IL_0050:  ldloc.0     
IL_0051:  callvirt    System.Action<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,System.Object>.Invoke
IL_0056:  ret
```

If you look at this line:

```
IL_0012:  ldstr       "ActuallyNotPresentMethod"
```

you can see that the name of the method to call is actually embedded in the IL as a string literal.

If we were to change the code to not use `dynamic`, and call `Execute` that exists, we get:

```
IL_0000:  newobj      UserQuery+Test..ctor
IL_0005:  callvirt    UserQuery+Test.Execute
IL_000A:  ret
```

You can see that the call is done completely different.

This explains the exception. The code is using `dynamic` to invoke a method, and this string is not obfuscated and thus contains the original unobfuscated method name. Since this method no longer exists with that name, the exception is thrown at runtime from the runtime binder.

Why, exactly, AgileDotNet missed dynamic I have no idea. It could be that it just doesn't handle `dynamic` at all, in which case you will have to deal with that. You should reach out to [Secureteam](http://www.secureteam.net/acode) to seek help figuring out what the tool is able to provide, if anything at all.

Comment: Thanks! You were spot on with the `dynamic`. In my case, I was passing a `dynamic` parameter to `MyFunctionActualName` function as opposed to calling a function where `this` is dynamic.